# Plotly.js 3D Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, plotly, plotly.js

I'm working on building a plotly.js 3D animation using NextJS. I have used the 2D example given on the website as an example, however when turning it to a 3dscatter, the points do not animate. The slider will move, but the data points do not update. I have previously created something similar in R, but the conversion isn't working as I'd expect in JavaScript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included my code below updated to be 3D.

```
var lookup = {};

    function getData(year, continent) {
      var byYear, trace;
      if (!(byYear = lookup[year])) {
        byYear = lookup[year] = {};
      }
      // If a container for this year + continent doesn't exist yet,
      // then create one:
      if (!(trace = byYear[continent])) {
        trace = byYear[continent] = {
          x: [],
          y: [],
          z: [],
          id: [],
          text: [],
          marker: { size: [] },
        };
      }
      return trace;
    }

    // Generate made-up data
    var data = [
      {
        year: 2000,
        continent: 'Asia',
        country: 'Japan',
        lifeExp: 82.6,
        gdpPercap: 35000,
        pop: 126000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      {
        year: 2000,
        continent: 'Asia',
        country: 'China',
        lifeExp: 72.4,
        gdpPercap: 5000,
        pop: 1290000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      {
        year: 2000,
        continent: 'Africa',
        country: 'Nigeria',
        lifeExp: 56.9,
        gdpPercap: 2000,
        pop: 123000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      {
        year: 2001,
        continent: 'Asia',
        country: 'Japan',
        lifeExp: 85.6,
        gdpPercap: 135000,
        pop: 1126000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      {
        year: 2001,
        continent: 'Asia',
        country: 'China',
        lifeExp: 82.4,
        gdpPercap: 15000,
        pop: 11290000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      {
        year: 2001,
        continent: 'Africa',
        country: 'Nigeria',
        lifeExp: 66.9,
        gdpPercap: 12000,
        pop: 1123000000,
        z: 92983
      },
      // Add more data rows for different years, continents, and countries...
    ];

    // Go through each row, get the right trace, and append the data:
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var datum = data[i];
      var trace = getData(datum.year, datum.continent);
      trace.text.push(datum.country);
      trace.id.push(datum.country);
      trace.x.push(datum.lifeExp);
      trace.y.push(datum.gdpPercap);
      trace.z.push(datum.z);
      trace.marker.size.push(datum.pop);
    }

    // Get the group names:
    var years = Object.keys(lookup);
    // In this case, every year includes every continent, so we
    // can just infer the continents from the *first* year:
    var firstYear = lookup[years[0]];
    var continents = Object.keys(firstYear);

    // Create the main traces, one for each continent:
    var traces = [];
    for (i = 0; i < continents.length; i++) {
      var data = firstYear[continents[i]];
      // One small note. We're creating a single trace here, to which
      // the frames will pass data for the different years. It's
      // subtle, but to avoid data reference problems, we'll slice
      // the arrays to ensure we never write any new data into our
      // lookup table:
      traces.push({
        name: continents[i],
        x: data.x.slice(),
        y: data.y.slice(),
        z: data.z.slice(),
        id: data.id.slice(),
        text: data.text.slice(),
        type:  'scatter3d',
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {
          size: data.marker.size.slice(),
          sizemode: 'area',
          sizeref: 200000,
        },
      });
    }

    // Create a frame for each year. Frames are effectively just
    // traces, except they don't need to contain the *full* trace
    // definition (for example, appearance). The frames just need
    // the parts of the traces that change (here, the data).
    var frames = [];
    for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
      frames.push({
        name: years[i],
        data: continents.map(function (continent) {
          return getData(years[i], continent);
        }),
      });
    }

    // Now create slider steps, one for each frame. The slider
    // executes a plotly.js API command (here, Plotly.animate).
    // In this example, we'll animate to one of the named frames
    // created in the above loop.
    var sliderSteps = [];
    for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
      sliderSteps.push({
        method: 'animate',
        label: years[i],
        args: [
          [years[i]],
          {
            mode: 'immediate',
            transition: { duration: 300 },
            frame: { duration: 300, redraw: false },
          },
        ],
      });
    }

    var layout = {
      xaxis: {
        title: 'Life Expectancy',
        range: [30, 85],
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: 'GDP per Capita',
        type: 'log',
      },
      hovermode: 'closest',
      // We'll use updatemenus (whose functionality includes menus as
      // well as buttons) to create a play button and a pause button.
      // The play button works by passing `null`, which indicates that
      // Plotly should animate all frames. The pause button works by
      // passing `[null]`, which indicates we'd like to interrupt any
      // currently running animations with a new list of frames. Here
      // The new list of frames is empty, so it halts the animation.
      updatemenus: [
        {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          z: 0,
          yanchor: 'top',
          xanchor: 'left',
          showactive: false,
          direction: 'left',
          type: 'buttons',
          pad: { t: 87, r: 10 },
          buttons: [
            {
              method: 'animate',
              args: [
                null,
                {
                  mode: 'immediate',
                  fromcurrent: true,
                  transition: { duration: 300 },
                  frame: { duration: 500, redraw: false },
                },
              ],
              label: 'Play',
            },
            {
              method: 'animate',
              args: [
                [null],
                {
                  mode: 'immediate',
                  transition: { duration: 0 },
                  frame: { duration: 0, redraw: false },
                },
              ],
              label: 'Pause',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      // Finally, add the slider and use `pad` to position it
      // nicely next to the buttons.
      sliders: [
        {
          pad: { l: 130, t: 55 },
          currentvalue: {
            visible: true,
            prefix: 'Year:',
            xanchor: 'right',
            font: { size: 20, color: '#666' },
          },
          steps: sliderSteps,
        },
      ],
    };

    // Create the plot:
    Plotly.newPlot('Swing3DPlot', {
      data: traces,
      layout: layout,
      frames: frames,
    });
```